# Empty response to API call to Facebook Graph

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I have been hammering away at this problem for the last day. I really hope someone can help me out. I would be very grateful.

What I am trying to do is fetch event data from a Facebook Page. I looked over the documentation, which says this about reading Pages data:

> **Reading**
>
> A Facebook page
>
> **Permissions**
>
> For pages that are published, you need:
>
> - An app or user access token to view fields from fully public pages.

So what I did was I obtained an app access token via:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
            client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
           &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
           &grant_type=client_credentials
```

which then returned

```
access_token=MY_APP_ID|MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

After this I followed the documentation and made the following call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/129511477069092/events?fields=id,cover,name,venue,description&access_token=MY_APP_ID|MY_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This returned:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

So after some fiddling around I was able to make the call by switching to version V2.2 and by creating an access key with Facebook API Graph explorer tool(no permissions granted).

```
    GET    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/129511477069092/events?
fields=id,cover,name,venue,description&
access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_FACEBOOK_API_EXPLORER_TOOL
```

The page I am trying to retrieve data from is public and so are the events, so I can't figure out what is going on. I know I am super close since I am able to retrieve the data with the token provided by the Facebook API Graph Explorer Tool. The thing with using this token is that it only last a few hours and I need something that is going to last longer such as an app access token. I have done some research on Stackoverflow and found similar questions, but none of them solve my problem. Any help will be appreciated to the max! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug of v2.4 to me. It works with v2.3 if you remove the deprecated `venue` field:

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=129511477069092%2Fevents%3Ffields%3Did%2Ccover%2Cname%2Cdescription&version=v2.3

If the version is changed to v2.4, it returns an empty result.

- https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=129511477069092%2Fevents%3Ffields%3Did%2Ccover%2Cname%2Cdescription&version=v2.4

There's no documentation about this in the changelog at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

so I guess it's a bug. There's already a bug report at

- https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/443054055873667/

with status `assigned`. If you have an app that supports v2.3, I'd suggest you prefix your request like this:

```
GET /v2.3/129511477069092/events?fields=id,cover,name,description
```